# Permit extra params in special cases with Strong Params in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

So for an organization, I want users to be able to be able to edit some things about it.

```
params.require(:organization).permit(:name, :location)
```

But in special cases, I want administrators to be able to edit extra attributes

```
params.require(:organization).permit(:name, :location, :secrets)
```

Now I know I can just have an if statement to choose which line I want to use, but since the admin will always be able to edit the original attributes, I wanted to easily be able to include them like so:

```
permitted = params.require(:organization).permit(:name, :location)
permitted.permit(:secrets) if current_user.admin?
```

Is there any way to chain permit calls like that? Or do I have to do something like store the attributes in an array and conditionally add extra before making the permit call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the below technique, there's no need to write the same params twice, which is helpful if you have a long list of attributes.

```
def organization_params
  attributes = [:name, :location]
  attributes.push(:secrets) if current_user.admin?

  params.require(:organization).permit(attributes)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the way to go:

```
def permitted_params
  if current_user.admin?
    params.require(:organization).permit(:name, :location, :secrets)
  else
    params.require(:organization).permit(:name, :location)
  end
end
```

Then use `permitted_params` in your controller.

Comment: This appears to only allow secrets, it won't also allow name and location

Comment: yep, it seems not possible to chain permits. only requires

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this, especially because I have a lot of attributes. I'll post an answer with what I'm doing unless someone figures something better out

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is simple:

```
def organization_params
  basic_filter = %w(name location)
  filter = user.admin? ? basic_filter.push('secrets') : basic_filter
  params.require(:organization).permit(filter)
end
```

This will work as you see:

```
[20] pry(main)> params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
[20] pry(main)*     organization: {  
[20] pry(main)*       name: 'Francesco',    
[20] pry(main)*       location:  'L.A.',    
[20] pry(main)*       secrets: 'secrets'    
[20] pry(main)*     }    
[20] pry(main)* })    
=> {"organization"=>{"name"=>"Francesco", "location"=>"L.A.", "secrets"=>"secrets"}}
[21] pry(main)> basic_filter = %w(name location)
=> ["name", "location"]
[22] pry(main)> filter = true ? basic_filter.push('secrets') : basic_filter
=> ["name", "location", "secrets"]
[23] pry(main)> params.require(:organization).permit(filter)
=> {"name"=>"Francesco", "location"=>"L.A.", "secrets"=>"secrets"}
```

and if `user.admin?` is **false**, the result will be

```
[26] pry(main)> basic_filter
=> ["name", "location", "secrets"]
[27] pry(main)> basic_filter = %w(name location)
=> ["name", "location"]
[28] pry(main)> filter = false ? basic_filter.push('secrets') : basic_filter
=> ["name", "location"]
[29] pry(main)> params.require(:organization).permit(filter)
Unpermitted parameter: secrets
=> {"name"=>"Francesco", "location"=>"L.A."}
```

This may help you.

Comment: This seems like a slightly more complicated version of my answer, but thanks for trying!

Comment: @TMP yep, actually I think I did exactly what you have done. It is because I began to answer this question when there was only one answer(not yours), and I was interrupted by something soon. When I came back and completed my answer, I found your answer had been there... I feel so sorry that I want to add a comment to your answer to let you know I've made a duplicate answer but failed. Because I was noticed I must have 50 reputation to comment. : (

Comment: No worries! Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. Good luck on your journey to gain the ability to comment!